# codeigniter form response as json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

In my codeigniter application I have a form in my views and I want to pass the responses received from this form in json format for further use. Can anyone guide me on steps to do the same please

Comment: do you want to get json on client side or server side?

Comment: @geekbro , that would be server side

Comment: we can get your data in form of an array and then can use **json_encode()**  to make it a JSON

Comment: can you link any example of the same?

Comment: i added  an answer. @nikita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code might help

```
 $arr=['name'=>'Ankita','education'=>'Graduate'];

 $json=json_encode($arr);

 var_dump($json);
```

The result would be

```
string(40) "{"name":"Ankita","education":"Graduate"}"
```